# Website appears blank when accessed through google, but loads fine if you go to index.php page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I had an infection go through my whole website, where a encode(base64()) was injected and it was adding a lot of hidden content onto pages that people could not see, but crawlers could. I went through and I deleted a lot of that code. But what happened next, puzzles me.

If I was to go to google and search for buckynet, the link appears #5 and should take you to the page at www.buckynet.org/index.php , which it doesn't, it takes you straight to the blank page and sits there... If I was to type buckynet.org into my browser, it would take me to the right spot... what did I screw up?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with your code... I think it's an issue with your web host.

When I click on the search link in Google, I'm getting the following headers:

```
Request URL:http://www.buckynet.org/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

**Request Headers:**
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=lebmk3p73rpnralugsecmnvhk3; __qca=P0-875483401-1381177673275
Host:www.buckynet.org
Referer:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEUQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buckynet.org%2F&ei=MxlTUpjdDeboiALH8IDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFQkHsKVWhjSyMkEQe67t0jpl6pCQ&sig2=kvqItrvhgwvdx0bZf2lZLQ&bvm=bv.53537100,d.cGE
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 07 Oct 2013 20:34:09 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
```

Where as when I go directly to www.buckynet.org, I get these headers:

```
Request URL:http://www.buckynet.org/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

**Request Headers**
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=lebmk3p73rpnralugsecmnvhk3; __qca=P0-875483401-1381177673275
Host:www.buckynet.org
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 07 Oct 2013 20:38:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Location:http://buckynet.org/
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
X-Pingback:http://buckynet.org/wordpress/xmlrpc.php
```

Note the status code 200 OK in the first case, and 301 Moved Permanently in the second case.

But, Diodeus is right.. .without the code of your index.php and possibly .htaccess you have on that site, we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have a redirect set up so that you drop the `www` from the url when people try to access your site.

When a user goes to your site - `http://www.mysite.com` - it redirects correctly - `http://mysite.com` - but when the request comes from Google it appears not to redirect and hence shows a blank page.

---

I began messing around with parameters and *thought I had it narrowed down* until I checked and it does now appear to be working... Have you changed anything?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` files. Most of the time, attackers inject code in there, that checks the referrer and redirects your page to some other site if it's coming from Google/Yahoo etc. And if you visit your site directly, it won't redirect.